# How to switch from 24hr to 12hr clock in Highstock chart?

Tags: highcharts

I am using highstock for stock charts. Currently the xAxis data are in 24 hr format for intraday.
I want to display the intraday data in 12 hrs format for xAxis.

Can you please tell me how to convert 24hrs time to 12 hrs in Highstock charts??
I tried with dateTimeLabelFormats, but no luck.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

For me dateTimeLabelFormats works perfectly fine, see: http://jsfiddle.net/wmFZx/

```
$('#container').highcharts({
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        dateTimeLabelFormats: {
            hour: '%I %p'
        }
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
        pointStart: Date.UTC(2010, 0, 1),
        pointInterval: 2 * 3600 * 1000 // two hours
    }]
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.For xAxis labels showing fine in 12hrs but I used this for toolTip but doesn't change. tooltip: {
                
               
                dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                    hour: '%I %p'
                }
            },

Comment: Looks like for tooltip used is different format, try to change for a day: http://jsfiddle.net/wmFZx/1/

Comment: Could you show screenshot? However, in that case, you can always use formatter instead: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.formatter

Answer (score 1):

For those coming in late like me(2yrs later), try this:

```
tooltip: {
  xDateFormat: "%A, %b %e, %I:%M%p"
},
xAxis: {
  dateTimeLabelFormats : {
    hour: "%I %p"
  }
}
```

Here's the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4tat369x/

If you have multiple series and share the tooltip, you'll want to modify the dataGrouping dateTimeLabelFormats for your type of chart. Here's what it looks like for a line chart:

```
plotOptions: {
  line: {
    dataGrouping: {
      dateTimeLabelFormats: {
        millisecond: ["%A, %b %e, %H:%M:%S.%L%p", "%A, %b %e, %I:%M:%S.%L%p", "-%I:%M:%S.%L%p"],
        second: ["%A, %b %e, %I:%M:%S%p", "%A, %b %e, %I:%M:%S%p", "-%I:%M:%S%p"],
        minute: ["%A, %b %e, %I:%M%p", "%A, %b %e, %I:%M%p", "-%I:%M%p"],
        hour: ["%A, %b %e, %I:%M%p", "%A, %b %e, %I:%M%p", "-%I:%M%p"],
        day: ["%A, %b %e, %Y", "%A, %b %e", "-%A, %b %e, %Y"],
        week: ["Week from %A, %b %e, %Y", "%A, %b %e", "-%A, %b %e, %Y"],
        month: ["%B %Y", "%B", "-%B %Y"],
        year: ["%Y", "%Y", "-%Y"]
      }
    }
  }
}
```